# Android sending information to server through wifi service

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to create an application which should send some information to the PC using wifi connection(Like the concept of file transfer in bluetooth).

I am totally new to wifi and networking. Any one please suggest me any idea for this so that it will be very helpful to me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Keep in Mind***:

> **TRUE**: You and your apps are working and executing commands on the proccessor.
>
> **FALSE**: You are in charge

`Where am I heading?`

> If you are a program, you do not care for `HOW` but all you care is to `GET A CONNECTION` to a certain IP. 
>   Whether the OS gives you the connection through *wifi* or *lan*, this is not your decidion.
>
> The boss is the OS. You are simply being bossy under its shades!.

---

[Start Learning Sockets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)

---

Comment: Fine Sherif, i am learning about sockets. I created a sample application in eclipse to send data through socket to the server and got it working. Can i get this socket data in my php code?